# Как присвоить значение элементу двумерного динамического массива, созданного с помощью контейнера <vector>

Tags: c++, массивы, vector, stl

Массив задается следующим образом

```
vector < vector <int> > v;
```

Затем, когда я пытаюсь присвоить значения элементам массива, для вот такого присвоения

```
v[a][b] = i;
```

Компилятор выдает вот такое сообщение
error: invalid types 'gnu_cxx::alloc_traits::value_type {aka int}[int]' for array subscript

А при присвоении с помощью функции

```
v[a].push_back(i);
```

error: request for member 'push_back' in 'v.std::vector::operatora))', which is of non-class type 'gnu_cxx::alloc_traits::value_type' {aka 'int'}
v[a].push_back(i);

Как исправить эту ошибку, чтобы можно было присваивать значения и прямым обращением к элементу массива, и с помощью функции push_back(x)?

Если что, переменные a, b и i являются переменными типа int и имеют значения не более 10

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что у вас не `vector<int> v;`? Ну не может быть таких ошибок с `vector<vector<int>> v;`

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. При таком объявлении `v` таких ошибок в ответ на ваш код быть не может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector< vector<int> > v1(2 * a, vector<int>(2 * b));
v1[a][b] = i;
```

или

```
vector< vector<int> > v2;
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * a; ++i)
    v2.push_back(vector<int>(2*b));
v2[a][b] = i;
```

у вас вектор был пустой, потому вы не можете присвоить значение какому то элементу, а вектор нужно заполнять соответствующим типом элементов. В вашем случаи  тип значения является вектором

### Дополнение:

если a <= 10 и b <= 10, то  можно использовать это условие:

```
vector< vector<int> > v1(11, vector<int>(11));
    v1[a][b] = i;  

vector< vector<int> > v2;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    v2.push_back(vector<int>(11));
v2[a][b] = i;
```

Comment: и еще: не называйте вектор массивом...

Comment: А почему 2 * a и 2 * b ?

Comment: это к примеру: самое главное, чтобы вектор имел больше элементов, чем   индекс, который вы собираетесь использовать. Можете брать a + 1  или 100 * a или любое другое число больше  a